# RuntimeModelerException: A WebService annotation is not present on class: clientpackage.IClientPortClass

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, webservice-client, weblogic-10.x

I created a JAX-WS client with JDK 1.6.0_45. I use the produced jar in a war project, which is also packed in ear.
In Tomcat, I can call using webservice client and get response with no problem. However in **Weblogic 10.3.6 server**, I get this exception:

```
ClientPortClass service = new ClientPortClass();
IClientPortClass port = service.getPortXML(); ---> this line produces below error:

com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: A WebService annotation is not present on class: clientpackage.IClientPortClass
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:237)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.buildRuntimeModel(WSServiceDelegate.java:762)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider$ServiceDelegate.buildRuntimeModel(WLSProvider.java:1026)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createSEIPortInfo(WSServiceDelegate.java:746)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(WSServiceDelegate.java:737)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:361)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider$ServiceDelegate.internalGetPort(WLSProvider.java:978)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider$ServiceDelegate$PortClientInstanceFactory.createClientInstance(WLSProvider.java:1083)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientInstancePool.takeSimpleClientInstance(ClientInstancePool.java:376)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientInstancePool.take(ClientInstancePool.java:232)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider$ServiceDelegate.getPort(WLSProvider.java:896)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:344)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider$ServiceDelegate.getPort(WLSProvider.java:836)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:326)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:92)
    at clientpackage.ClientPortClass.getPortXML(ClientPortClass.java:58)
    ...
```

I checked ClientPortClass class produced by jax ws, it has this structure:

```
/**
 * Web Service
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.2.8
 * Generated source version: 2.1
 */
@WebServiceClient(name = "ClientPortClass", targetNamespace = "transactionData:ClientPortClass", wsdlLocation = "wsdlURL...")
public class ClientPortClass extends Service{
...
 @WebEndpoint(name = "portXML")
    public IClientPortClass getPortXML(WebServiceFeature... features) {
    ...}
}
```

IClientPortClass:

```
/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.2.8
 * Generated source version: 2.1
 */
@WebService(name = "IClientPortClass", targetNamespace = "transactionData:ClientPortClass")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface IClientPortClass {

    @WebMethod(action = "trigger")
    @WebResult(name = "message", targetNamespace = "transactionData:data", partName = "result")
    public Message trigger(
        @WebParam(name = "requestMessage", targetNamespace = "transactionData:data", partName = "input")
        RequestMessage input);
}
```

I observed weblogic uses glassfish.jaxws.rt_1.3.0.0_2-1-5.jar. com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException comes from that jar. I dont know but maybe it relates.

Do you have any suggestions to RuntimeModelerException: A WebService annotation is not present on class: clientpackage.IClientPortClass?

Comment: nobody has an answer/comment? Thanks in advance..

Comment: I've got the same pb, have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the @WebService annotation to the implement class, for example
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com...", targetNamespace = "http://abc...")

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this error for days. Here my solution that works for me under weblogic 10.3.6 .
Don't use apache cxf or other tools. 
Create the client with wsimport, provided with jdk starting from 1.6.

```
wsimport -p com.sample -keep -verbose http://yourservice?wsdl
```

Use the wsimport tool placed under the jdk used to compile project.
Check your weblogic-application.xml and if is present javax.jws.* comment it out.

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:package-name>antlr.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
    <!-- 
    <wls:package-name>javax.jws.*</wls:package-name>
     -->
</wls:prefer-application-packages>
```